# Why are uploaded files getting a httpd_tmp_t label when a custom temp dir is used?

Tags: php, linux, selinux, tmp

When I use PHP's `move_uploaded_file` function to upload files in to a directory, those files have the label `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` and inherit the parent directory's ACLs. If I configure PHP to use a custom created temp directory, the uploaded files are instead labelled `httpd_tmp_t` and lose the ACL.

What causes this to happen?

The temp directory resides in `/var/www/project/tmp`. It has a mode of 1777 and a label of `tmp_t`.

The upload directory resides in `/var/www/project/uploads` and is writable by the PHP process and has a label of `httpd_sys_rw_content_t`. Files created inside it also have this label and inherit the ACLs of its parent, except in this strange case.

I would say this is the result of moving files from one location to another, but why does it not do this for `/tmp`?

- Rocky Linux 8
- PHP 8.1

Comment: Show your upload script please

Comment: @KenLee This sounds like something being done automatically by the OS, not the script.

Comment: @KenLee this isn't specific to any particular upload script. I can repro it on several different web apps that use move_uploaded_file. Certainly, those apps are not doing any other file operations on those files.

Comment: Just to make sure that you will not accidentally concatenate the source into the target.

Answer (score 0):

There is a file transition saying that when a process with the type `httpd_t` creates a file in a directory with the type `tmp_t`, it applies the type `httpd_tmp_t`.

If you are expecting the `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` type for the files created in this directory, you should set this type to the directory:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/project/tmp(/.*)?"
restorecon -RF /var/www/project/tmp
```

Comment: But `/tmp` (or where systemd's private temp ultimately is in `/tmp`) doesn't have `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` as far as I can tell, yet the files end up inheriting that context from the uploads directory.